# MySQL Select Case - Comparison Between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have two tables similar to these:

```
Table: case

---------------------------------------------------
| id |  company | managed |    time    |  client  |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  apple   |   yes   | 1412643785 |    no    |
---------------------------------------------------
| 2  |  barilla |   no    | 1412643785 |    no    |
---------------------------------------------------
| 3  |  google  |   no    | 1412643785 |   yes    |
---------------------------------------------------
| 4  |  google  |   yes   | 1412643785 |   yes    |
---------------------------------------------------
| 5  |  google  |   no    | 1412643785 |   yes    |
---------------------------------------------------


Table: language

---------------------------
| id | company  |  lang   |
---------------------------
| 1  |  apple   |   EN    |
---------------------------
| 2  |  barilla |   IT    |
---------------------------
| 3  |  google  |   EN    |
---------------------------
```

I have create statistics/graphics from this tablet, the I extract the following information for each month:
* Number of cases of clients per month
* Number of cases managed per month
* Total number of cases per month
* Number of cases of Italian companies per month

For the first three points I don't have no problems, and I have made this query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%M') as 'Month', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN client = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Reports of a customer,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN managed = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Managed cases',
    COUNT(id) as 'Total reports'
FROM case
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m')
```

**But how do I extract the monthly number of cases managed of any Italian company?**

I tried to add this portion of query but does not go...

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN case.company = language.company AND language.lang = 'IT'  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Italian Case',
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: You do need to join the language table.

Answer (score 1):

Your thought was right, just needed to join the additional table:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time, '%Y-%M') as 'Month', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.client = 'yes' THEN 1 END) as 'Reports of a customer',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.managed = 'yes' THEN 1 END) as 'Managed cases',
    COUNT(t.id) as 'Total reports',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN language.lang = 'IT'  THEN 1 END) as 'Italian Case',
FROM case t
JOIN language ON language.company = t.company
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time, '%Y-%m')
```

Please note that I removed `ELSE NULL` from your cases as it is the default.